# How update different UI components using one UI state and ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I have a screen, a ViewModel, and a UI state (a sealed class with loading object and a data class). I want to use my screen with various UI components (example: a row with stories and a column with a card). I have a UI state and a ViewModel through which I update my UI state. When I load data for the screen, all data updates are synchronized (if the stories are loaded within 10 seconds, then the entire screen will load within 10 seconds).

But if I want to update **one** of all components (example: the user clicks on the button to update **only** stories and ** only** stories have been updated), how can I do this? Example: A user clicks on the refresh stories button and scrolls through the cards while updating stories

Do I understand correctly that I have to use different fields in the ViewModel that I observe on the screen, and is it possible to implement this with a single UIState? Then how do I put it all on my screen?

**Current UiState.kt**

```kotlin
sealed class UiState {
    object Loading : UiState()
    data class Content(
        val stories: List<Story>,
        val cards: List<Card>
    ) : UiState()
}
```

**Current ScreenViewModel.kt**

```kotlin
class ScreenViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    private var _uiState: MutableStateFlow<UiState> = MutableStateFlow(UiState.Loading)
    val uiState: StateFlow<UiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val stories = async { /* load stories */ }
            val cards = async { /* load cards */ }
            _uiState.value = UiState.Content(stories.await(), cards.await())
        }
    }
}
```

**Current MyScreen.kt** (Jetpack Compose)

```kotlin
val uiState = vm.uiState.collectAsState()
AnimatedContent(uiState) { state ->
    when (state) {
        UiState.Loading -> {} // Loading UI
        is UiState.Content -> {} // Show Content UI
    }
}
```

I use one UiState class (it update full screen every time) or I use different values in view model without UiState. How can I update one component? (use self ui state for every component?)

**New viewmodel**

```kotlin
class MyViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    private var _stories: MutableStateFlow<List<Story>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())
    private var _cards: MutableStateFlow<List<Card>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())
    val cards = _cards.asStateFlow()
    val stories = _stories.asStateFlow()
    
    init {
        getStories()
        getCards() 
    }
    
    fun getStories(): List<Story>
    ....

    fun getCards(): List<Card>
    ....
}
```

**New screen**

```kotlin
val cards = vm.cards.collectAsState()
val storiees = vm.storiees.collectAsState()

LazyRow {
    items(stories) {
        StoryItem(it)
    }
}

Button(onClick = { vm.updateStories() }) {
    Text(text = "Update stories")
}
```

Thank you if you tell us about it in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use combine function to combine two flows

```
class ScreenViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    private val storyFlow = MutableStateFlow<List<Story>?>(null)
    private val cardFlow = MutableStateFlow<List<Card>?>(null)

    val uiState = combine(storyFlow, cardFlow) { stories, cards ->
        if (stories == null || cards == null) UiState.Loading
        else UiState.Content(stories, cards)
    }.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = UiState.Loading
    )

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            storyFlow.update { /* get stories */ }
        }
        
        viewModelScope.launch { 
            cardFlow.update { /* get cards */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! I will definitely try your solution